# не работает unban в дискорд боте (disnake)

Tags: python, disnake

Написал unban.py(мой код разделен на коги) у меня что-то вышло, но не сработало. Работает все это с слэшом и при попытке ввести ID пользователя выходит ошибка в дискорде: "Введите корректный числовой код". Помогите пожалуйста
КОД:

````
from disnake.ext import commands

class Unban(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.slash_command(brief="<ID пользователя>", description="Разбанить пользователя по ID")
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, user_id: int):
        try:
            user = await self.bot.fetch_user(user_id)
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        except disnake.NotFound:
            return await ctx.send("Пользователь не найден в списке забаненных.")
        except disnake.Forbidden:
            return await ctx.send("У меня нет прав на разбан пользователя.")

        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title="Разбан",
            description=f"Пользователь {user.mention} был разбанен.\nПожалуйста, не нарушайте больше правила.",
            color=disnake.Color.green()
        )

        # Проверка наличия аватара
        if user.avatar:
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar.url)
        
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Модератор: {ctx.author}#{ctx.author.discriminator}")

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Unban(bot))```
````

Answer (score 0):

ID пользователя больше по размеру чем int. Поэтому или используй свободное поле без указанного типа данных и преобразуй в int при поиске или настрой их в commands.Param(). Более детально смотри данный метод в документации диснейка.

Надеюсь я не поздно ответил